# add variables from Ansible inventory file to a dynamic inventory

Tags: dynamic, ansible, ansible-inventory

i have an inventory file containing 200 servers and thier respective variables as shown in a sample below:

```
[myhost1.mrsh.com]
myhost1.mrsh.com ORACLE_HOME=/u/orahome12/middleware/12c_db1 ansible_user=wladmin

[myhost2.mrsh.com]
myhost2.mrsh.com ORACLE_HOME=/u/orahome12/middleware/12c_db1 ansible_user=wladmin

..........
........
```

i ask the user to enter any hostname which is passed to  `hostnames` variable as below:

```
ansible-playbook /web/playbooks/automation/applycpupatch/applycpupatch.yml -i /web/playbooks/automation/applycpupatch/applycpupatch.hosts -f 5 -e action=status -e hostnames='myhost1
myhost2' -e patch_file='p33286132_122130_Generic.zip'
```

if `myhost1` is present in the `applycpupatch.hosts` file i then wish to create a dynamic inventory using `add_host` having only `myhost1` and its variables like `ORACLE_HOME`

Below is my code:

```
- name: "Play 1 - Set Destination details"
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item | upper }}"
        groups: dest_nodes
        ansible_user: "{{ hostvars[item + '*'].ansible_user }}"
        ORACLE_HOME: "{{ hostvars[item + '*'].ORACLE_HOME }}"
      when: inventory_hostname | regex_search(item)"
      with_items: "{{ hostnames.split() }}"
```

Unfortunately, i get the error as below:

```
TASK [add_host] ****************************************************************
Saturday 20 November 2021  19:05:38 -0600 (0:00:00.059)       0:00:23.532 ***** 
[0;31mfatal: [myhost222.mrsh.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'inventory_hostname | regex_search(item)\"' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected char '\"' at 45. String: {% if inventory_hostname | regex_search(item)\" %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/web/playbooks/automation/applycpupatch/applycpupatch.yml': line 36, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - add_host:\n      ^ here\n"}[0m
```

I also tried the below but it fails with the error.

```
ORACLE_HOME: "{{ hostvars['all'][item + '*'].ORACLE_HOME }}"
```

Thus my dynamic inventory constructed runtime `dest_nodes` in this example should have ONLY the below.

```
myhost1.mrsh.com ORACLE_HOME=/u/orahome12/middleware/12c_db1 ansible_user=wladmin
myhost2.mrsh.com ORACLE_HOME=/u/orahome12/middleware/12c_db1 ansible_user=wladmin
```

Comment: Rhetoric question: Did you debug `hostvars` to see its content and did you find there any dict key named (literally) `"myhost1*"`, `"myhost2*"` or `"all"` ? Moreover, you are reinventing the wheel as those hosts are already in you inventory with their variables. Just use a limit and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand very well what do you want, but you have lot of errors to fix in your playbook:

1-  launch your playbook with -e hostnames='myhost1,myhost2'

2- fix your playbook: you have to test the result of your regex_search, use the variable inventory_hostname and use split(','):

a sample

```
- name: "Play 1 - Set Destination details"
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}   -  {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ORACLE_HOME }}"
      when: (inventory_hostname | regex_search(item)) != ''        
      with_items: "{{ hostnames.split(',') }}"
```